# How can I pass an Object from my $http.get to my c# API?

Tags: c#, angularjs, api

I create a c# api

```
[Route("api/filters")]
[HttpGet]
public Filters Select(Filters filters)
{
    return filters;
}
```

and my angularjs call my c# api

```
var filters = {
    idFilter1 : 12,
    idFilter2 : 16
}

$http({ 
 url: 'api/filters',
 method: 'get',
 data: { filters : filters } })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    });
```

I try to modify my code in differents ways but my `console.log(response.data)` always return null
Someone have any idea how to do that ?

**UPDATE**

I try to use params instead of data

Comment: You have a typo: `filtres: filters`

Comment: What's the response status code? Try logging the entire response, or use the Network tab of the browser's Developer tools to see the actual response and any error messages

Comment: @piertoni I just forget to translate `filtres`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the response is just `null`

Comment: You are not usually supposed to have body data in GET requests. I don't know if that is related to the problem, I would never do that.

Comment: @Crowcoder then how can I do it I remove [FromBody] but I still get nothing

Comment: POST instead of GET. Of course, I don't know what the actual problem is, just saying in general you should POST (or put or patch or delete, etc) if there is a request body.

Comment: @Crowcoder so if I use an object I'm forced to use POST ?

Comment: No, you should be able make GET work but it is unconventional and I'm not sure if there is some kind of configuration you have to set in your API to enable it.

Comment: @Crowcoder ok thank you for your help